# Event Form Symfony2.1

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to use the listener of the form (try with pre_set_data and pre_bind), but I get this error

The required option "class" is missing.

```
 public function bindData(DataEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData(); 
    $form = $event->getForm();


    if (null === $data) {
        return;
    }



    $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('citta','entity', array(
                    'label' => 'form.citta',
                    'empty_value' => 'form.scelta',
                    'required' => true,
                    'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
                    'class' => 'MyBundle:GeoNames',
                    'property' => 'geonameid',
                    'query_builder' => function(\MyBundle\GeoBundle\Entity\GeoNamesRepository $er) {
                        //return $er->getCountry();
                    },
        )));
    //}
}
```

the same if it's put in veins formtype seen properly

i try also

```
$form->add($this->factory->createNamed('citta','entity',null, array(
```

but i have

```
Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "NULL" given
```

I am following the cookbook

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `'class' => 'MyBundleGeoBundle:GeoNames',` instead?

Comment: I corrected only for entering the post.
'class' => 'MybundleGeoBundle:GeoNames',

Comment: Are you sure the error is on this part of the code?

Comment: Is it solved? If not, can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: it solved, the wrong path of the entity

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
$form->add($this->factory->createNamed('citta','entity', null, array(
```

See code: /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php at line 45